# Date not saving while posting in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, date-formatting

My application is developed in ***Asp.net MVC3*** coded in ***C#***, im getting the issue of **date formatting**.

**There are three fields on form**

1. First Name
2. Experience
3. Date_Of_Registration

This form post data well at my end, i.e in my local solution and also if i publish this application on my In-House server. The Date_of_Registration (**datetime field**) is also saved. Same application works fine at one of my client environment. But suddenly im getting this issue when i have published this application to a new client. The Date in Date_of_Registration column is not getting saved if i take the date greater than 12, if i select the date less than 12 then the date is getting saved. Also im getting the same issue while calling my SRS report, there is From-Date and To-Date field to get the records between two date but when i select the date greater than 12 then im getting the error as

**"The value provided for the report parameter 'ToDate' is not valid for its type. (rsReportParameterTypeMismatch)"**

**What i tried**

**1.** I tried to change the date format on the clientside on the machine that is application but it didnt worked.

**2.** I tried to change the date format on the client server on which application is hosted, but still im getting the same error.

**Please suggest.**

Comment: could you provide some code?

Comment: Sounds like a server culture issue. What culture are you expecting? Have you specified the culture in the web.config file? (e.g. `<globalization culture="en-AU" uiCulture="en-AU"/>`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke No, there is no culture declaration in my Web.config

Comment: Then its likely that the default cultures on the various servers are different.(the one with the problem has the date format "MM/dd/yyyy", whereas the ones that work have the date format "dd/MM/yyyy".  Try setting the culture in the `web.config` file.

Comment: @StephenMuecke The date format set on the machine that is having the issue is dd/MM/yyyy, this format works fine on other client but not on this

Comment: Check also the settings in IIS (.Net Globalization settings)